# netbeans 7.2 team server cloud Private project

Tags: cloud, private, netbeans-7

A Simple Question

Does netbeans clouds and team servers keep project sources private?

I am looking for a way to make a project in netbeans which only i can access and edit from anywhere where i can get internet connection, while no1 can download my sources?